# OpenVAS With NVT Feed Sync Error on Kail Linux and Ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, security-groups, openvas

Recently installed OpenVAS on Kail Linux and Ubuntu from ISO but have been running into an issue with the sync process.

1. When installed onto VMware Workstation via Kail VM image updates the openvas-Setup process all updates fine.
2. When Kail Linux with OpenVAS is installed via ISO then the below error appears.
3. The below error also appears when installed onto Ubuntu 16.04 with OpenVAS package.

bzip2: (stdin) is not a bzip2 file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

The NVT update is vial for the scans so I need help understanding why it is saying that it is not a bzip2 file.  The other feeds sync without an issue.

[NVT_bzip2_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rjk3Q.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Same error met and you can use this command to sync:

```
greenbone-nvt-sync --rsync
```